# Numpy zeros in array

Tags: python, numpy, dot-product

I'm trying to get maximum performance out of numpy and was wondering if there was a better way to calculate the dot product with an array that has a lot of zeros in it
for example:

```
a = np.array([[0, 3, 0], [1, 0, 1]])
print a.dot([1, 2, 5])
```

this is a small example but if we had a much larger scale array that has lets say 80% zeros at any place in the array, my question would be is there a better or preferably faster way to calculate the dot product when there are so many zeros?

Comment: Maybe using sparse matrices would be faster.

Comment: There is a `scipy.sparse` package that creates and uses sparse matrices.  But in my experience a matrix has to have a sparsity below 1% to gain a speed advantage over the `numpy` `dot` (ie. 99% zeros).

Comment: I'll look into sparse matrices but would you recommend using that all the time or just when its higher than 99% @hpaulj

Comment: There's enough of a learning curve and limitations that I wouldn't switch just to speed up a few `dot` products.   They were originally developed for large linear algebra problems (finite element, difference), but also now get use of machine learning.  What else do you use these matrices for?

Comment: Just dot product for now I might need to transpose them in the future but nothing else

Comment: Why don't you just give it a try? Creating a sparse matrix is as easy as `sparse.csr_matrix(dense_array)` transpose is as cheap as with dense matrices and the basic operations have the same syntax. To go back use `sparse_matrix.todense().A` unless you really, really want a `matrix` not `array` in which case leave out the `.A`.

Comment: That said, with 80% sparsity @hpaulj is most probably correct in that you shouldn't expect a speedup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [269]: from scipy import sparse
In [270]: M=sparse.random(1000,1000,.1, 'csr')
In [271]: MA = M.A
In [272]: timeit M*M.T
10 loops, best of 3: 64 ms per loop
In [273]: timeit MA@MA.T
10 loops, best of 3: 60.4 ms per loop
```

I defined a random sparse matrix with a specified sparsity, 10%:

```
In [274]: M
Out[274]: 
<1000x1000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 100000 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [275]: np.allclose(MA@MA.T, (M*M.T).A)
Out[275]: True
```

`@` is an operator form of `dot` (see `np.matmul`).  So at this 10% level of sparsity, the two approaches time the same (without any conversion to/from sparse).

For this random matrix, the `M*M.T` result is dense:

```
In [282]: (M*M.T)
Out[282]: 
<1000x1000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 999964 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

---

The sparse times depend heavily on sparsity; the dense times not at all

```
In [295]: M=sparse.random(1000,1000,.01, 'csr'); MA=M.A
In [296]: timeit M*M.T
100 loops, best of 3: 2.44 ms per loop
In [297]: timeit MA@MA.T
10 loops, best of 3: 56.3 ms per loop
In [298]: M=sparse.random(1000,1000,.2, 'csr'); MA=M.A
In [299]: timeit M*M.T
10 loops, best of 3: 175 ms per loop
In [300]: timeit MA@MA.T
10 loops, best of 3: 56.3 ms per loop
```

---

With a round trip to sparse and back, times jump from 60 to 100ms

```
In [302]: %%timeit
     ...: M1=sparse.csr_matrix(MA)
     ...: (M1*M1.T).A
     ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 104 ms per loop
```

Comment: @ did not work for me but instead I used MA.dot(MA.T)

Comment: I was just being lazy in a newer python/numpy. For 2d arrays like this results should be the same.